# Adding a progress bar to show how much percentage of form had been loaded

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I've a form having certain lines of code on the form_load event and thus it takes some time to be shown. I want to add a progress bar to show how much percentage of form has been loaded. How can I do so ..?

In short:- Like while browsing the web pages the progress as shown in web browser indicate the value of page has been loaded. I want to do so in vb.net.

How can I do so .?

Comment: If the code is in the `Load` event handler then the form hasn't been displayed yet, so where are you planning on displaying the `ProgressBar`?

Comment: A web browser does it by using threading, that is what you have to do as well.  BackgroundWorker makes it pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move your long running code into the form's `.Shown` event handler.

I would suggest adding a `StatusStrip` to your form and add a `ToolStripProgressBar` to that. I did this in a program I wrote and used the following bit of code work on it.

It's all pretty self explanatory :-)

```
''' <summary>
''' Sets minimum and maximum values for ToolStripProgressBar and shows it
''' </summary>
''' <param name="min">Minimum Value</param>
''' <param name="max">Maximum Value</param>
''' <param name="labeltext">Text to show in ToolStripLabel</param>
Private Sub SetAndShowProgressBar(min As Integer, max As Integer, labeltext As String)
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = labeltext
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Minimum = min
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = max + 5
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 1
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Visible = True
    StatusStrip1.Update()
End Sub


''' <summary>
''' Hides ToolStripProgressBar
''' </summary>
Private Sub HideProgressBar()
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ""
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Visible = False
    StatusStrip1.Update()
End Sub


Private Delegate Sub incprogressbarDelegate()


Private Sub IncrementProgressBar()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New incprogressbarDelegate(AddressOf IncrementProgressBar)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object())
    Else
        Me.ToolStripProgressBar1.Value += 1
        StatusStrip1.Update()
    End If
End Sub


Private Delegate Sub SetProgressBarDelegate(i As Integer)


Private Sub SetProgressBarValue(i As Integer)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetProgressBarDelegate(AddressOf SetProgressBarValue)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {i})
    Else
        Me.ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = i
    End If
End Sub
```